# pushViewController stuck or viewdidappear fail

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am just pushing new VC like this.

```
[nav pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

However, it doesn't push. The new view reach the state - viewwillappear but viewDidAppear fail to reach sometime. I can swipe back to go back. I have checked new view frame and it is also normal.

View frame is {{0, 64}, {320, 455}}. May I know where bug can occur?

Comment: How do you create `vc`?

Comment: I create normally like     CommentsDetailVC *vc = [[CommentsDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailVC" bundle:nil];

Comment: Issue happens only for that controller or for any other controller too?

Comment: sometime it happen for other controller too. I wonder what happen.

Comment: Could be the same issue as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503224/ios-app-freezes-on-pushviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your UIViewController is pushed or presented. If it is pushed then you can push a new UIViewController then you can push new view controller if it 
is presented then you can not push.

Comment: u mean my first VC? It is not created by pushing or presented. It is root VC. My second VC is pushed from my first VC.

Comment: No your current VC where you are pushing a new view controller.

Comment: it is not by presented though.

Comment: I faced the same issue and I was doing this mistake i.e. I was pushing a viewController(B) on A and then presenting a another viewController(C) on B and again I was pushing a new viewController(D) on C. In this case my viewController(D) was not pushing on B.